# Swift Combine: handle no data before decode without an error

Tags: swift, operator-keyword, combine, publisher

My API usually returns a certain format in JSON (simplified notation):

```
{
   status: // http status
   error?: // error handle
   data?:  // the response data
   ...
}
```

In my Combine operators, I take the `data` from a URLSession `dataTaskPublisher` and parse the response into a `Decodable` object that reflects the above schema. That works great.

However, I have an endpoint that returns the HTTP status code `201` (operation successful), and has **no data** at all. How would I chain this with my operators **without throwing an error**?

This is what I have:

```
publisher
.map { (data, response) in
    guard data.count > 0 else {
       let status = (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode
       return Data("{\"status\": \(status), \"data\": \"\"}".utf8)
    }
    return data
}
.mapError { CustomError.network(description: "\($0)")}
.decode(type: MyResponse<R>.self, decoder: self.agent.decoder)
.mapError { err -> CustomError in CustomError.decoding(description: "\(err)") }
...
```

As you can see, I simply construct an appropriate response, where the response's "data" is an empty string. However, this is ugly and a bit hacky, and I do not see the reason, why the pipeline should continue with parsing, etc, when I already have all I need. How can I interrupt it and finish the pipeline successfully for its final subscriber?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating a separate `Publisher` for handling the specific endpoint which doesn't return any `Data`. You can use a `tryMap` to check the HTTP status code and throw an error in case it's not in the accepted range. If you don't care about the result, only that there was a successful response, you can map to a `Void`. If you care about the result (or the status code), you can map to that too.

```
extension URLSession.DataTaskPublisher {
    func emptyBodyResponsePublisher() -> AnyPublisher<Void, CustomError> {
        tryMap { _, response in
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { throw CustomError.nonHTTPResponse }
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
            guard (200..<300).contains(statusCode) else { throw CustomError.incorrectStatusCode(statusCode) }
            return Void()
        }.mapError { CustomError.network($0) }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, that would work. I am trying to abstract that away from the caller... Maybe add an additional feature to my `Endpoint` if empty data is expected.

Comment: @Mundi if you want to abstract it away from the caller, you need to make sure the interface is the same - which results in a hacky workaround like the one you already came up with. You either need to modify the endpoint (if you can) or live with the fact that the caller needs to know that this specific endpoint returns no data - which shouldn't be a problem, since consumers of an API should be aware of what format each specific endpoint returns.